# Change All Login/Signup Links in Plugin

Tags: plugins, login, authentication, signup

I would like to redirect all login and signup links to an external site.

I would prefer to do this in a plugin, or somewhere that isn't affected by WordPress upgrades or theme changes.

What is the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you thinking of something similar to OpenID? http://openid.net/ where credentials are kept external from your site?

Comment: We are integrating WordPress with an existing system that has it's own user database. I've managed to get them to work together so that visiting WordPress from our other site will automatically login the user into WordPress. I need all the login and signup links in WordPress point to our other application's login and signup pages instead, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by putting the code below into a plugin.

```
class My_Class {

    public static function go_to_login() {
        global $pagenow, $theme_my_login, $redirect_to;

        if ( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
            $url = ( false === strpos( $redirect_to, 'wp-admin' ) ? $redirect_to : site_url() );
            wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/login?to=' . urlencode( $url ) );
            exit;
        }
    }

}

add_action( 'login_head', 'My_Class::go_to_login' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked over the `wordpress.org` plugin directory and I couldn't find anything... but you can always do this:

1) Create a copy of the wp-login.php and name it to something secret so you can always login later (like superlog_in1234.php)

2) Edit wp-login.php and look for all the `<form>` elements, and replace them with `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://website.com/">`. Unless you know what you're doing, don't change anything else.

3) Head to /wp-admin AND /wp-login.php and test if it works!

You can always login over at your secret login page, and this **what I use on my own website.**